# rspec mock not getting called on belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

I'm trying to test my controller in rails with RSpec, but it's not calling one of the mocks I made and I'm not sure why.

my model has a user class, and a game class, and a player class, which belongs to a user and a game.

I'm trying to test something like this

```
player = Player.find_by_id(params[:id])
if player != nil && player.user == current_user && player.game.remove_player?(player)
  redirect_to games_url
```

yet I can't seem to mock remove_player? correctly. What I'm doing is pretty much this:

```
@player = double("player")
Player.should_receive(:find_by_id).with(mock_player_id.to_s).and_return { @gplayer }
@player.stub(:user).and_return(@current_user)
fakeGame = double("game")
@player.stub(:game).and_return(fakeGame)
fakeGame.should_receive(:remove_player?).with(@player).and_return(true)
```

I'm getting the error saying that remove_player? was never called. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I can't tell for sure if it's reaching the player.user == curent_user, but it is calling find_by_id and not complaining about it at all, so I would imagine it must reach the user check.

EDIT: @current_user does equal current_user

Also, I tried replacing line 3 with

```
fakeUser = double("user")
@player.should_receive(:user).and_return(@current_user)
```

it gives me the error saying :user wasn't called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second line of your spec, return @player instead of @gplayer. If @gplayer isn't defined, your find_by_id will return nil in your spec, so your if condition will short circuit before it gets to remove_player.

Comment: man can't believe i spent 2 hours looking for something wrong and never found that. thanks. sorry for the dumb question.